# Turn on a Quicksettings tile automatically when I open a specific app?

Tags: 8.1-oreo, miui, proximity-sensor, quick-settings

[image]

I want to turn on proximity service tile when I open an app and turn off proximity service tile automatically, when I close the app.

Comment: [MacroDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.arlosoft.macrodroid) automation is one possibility, or any other [tag:automation] app

Comment: Thanks, but I can't find option to toggle quicksetting tile of my proximity service app (note that this is a separate downloaded app and not a feature of mobile), is there such option?

Comment: In that case, it may be better to search for an app that allows an automation shortcut. Not sure if such apps exist

Comment: Can you tell what do you mean by "automation shortcut"?

Comment: Apps that allow automation say so explicitly in their description. They provide a shortcut for activities such as on/off/toggle, that can be used by automation apps. If you find such an app, you can use automation tools to do the needful when an app is launched or closed